How to target a specific element of an array?
I'm currently working on a To-do-list from the odin project. As per the instructions, my todolist can create a new project, which we can then add tasks to the project. I now have a sidebar listing all existing projects, and when I click on any of the projects, it renders the details of the project onto the main body. I've attached screenshots of the page
before I click on a project

after I click on a project

I'm currently having trouble trying to add new tasks to the project that's active on the main body as I can't get its index.
In my addTaskModal.js module, I've created a dialog popup for users to input the details of the tasks to be added to the active project.
But I've been stuck for hours and I can't figure out how to get the index of the project that's rendered on the main page.
Here's my code that renders the project to the body:
import {
  addTaskModal
} from './addTaskModal.js';
import {
  myProjects
} from './myProjects.js';

const mainContent = document.querySelector('#main');

export default function renderMain(event) { //render project from sidebar to mainContent body

  mainContent.textContent = '';
  mainContent.appendChild(addTaskModal); //dialog to input new task and its priority

  let index = parseInt(event.target.id.split('-')[1]);



  const projectCard = document.createElement('div');
  projectCard.classList.add('card');

  const projectCardHeader = document.createElement('h3');
  projectCardHeader.classList.add('cardheader');
  projectCardHeader.textContent = myProjects[index].name
  projectCard.appendChild(projectCardHeader);

  const projectDue = document.createElement('div');
  projectDue.textContent = myProjects[index].due;
  projectDue.classList.add('date');
  projectCard.appendChild(projectDue);

  for (let i = 0; i < myProjects[index].tasks?.length; i++) {

    const tasks = document.createElement('div');
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    deleteBtn.textContent = 'Delete Task';
    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      myProjects[index].tasks.splice(i, 1);
      localStorage.setItem('projects', JSON.stringify(myProjects));
      renderMain(event);
    })

    //when we want to update after delete, just store with same "key" and the "key" will be updated.
    tasks.textContent = myProjects[index].tasks[i].name;
    tasks.classList.add('tasks');
    tasks.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    projectCard.appendChild(tasks);
  }
  const addTaskBtn = document.createElement('button');
  addTaskBtn.textContent = "Add Task";
  mainContent.appendChild(addTaskBtn);
  addTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    addTaskModal.showModal();
  });
  mainContent.appendChild(addTaskBtn);
  mainContent.appendChild(projectCard)
}

Here's the code for myProjects array for context:
let myProjects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('projects')) || [{
    name: "Go to supermarket",
    due: "12/2/25",
    tasks: [{
        name: "Buy apples",
        priority: "high"
      },
      {
        name: "Buy Eggs",
        priority: "medium"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Clean the house",
    due: "13/2/25",
    tasks: [{
        name: "Sweep and mop the floor",
        priority: "high"
      },
      {
        name: "Do laundry",
        priority: "high"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export {
  myProjects
};

Here's the addTaskModal.js to create a popup dialog for users to input details of the new task
import { myProjects } from "./myProjects";

const addTaskModal = document.createElement('dialog');

addTaskModal.classList.add('modal');
//const addTaskModal = document.createElement('div');

//addTaskModal.classList.add('hidden');

//create label and input box for user to input new task title
const newTask = document.createElement('div');
newTask.classList.add('modallabel');
newTask.textContent = "New Task :";
const newTaskInput = document.createElement('input');
newTaskInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Add New Task Here');
newTaskInput.setAttribute('id', 'newtaskinput');
newTaskInput.classList.add('inputbox');
newTask.appendChild(newTaskInput);

//create label and select input for user to input new task priority
const newPriority = document.createElement('div');
newPriority.textContent = "Priority: ";
newPriority.classList.add('prioritylabel');
const newPriorityInput = document.createElement('select');
newPriorityInput.setAttribute('id', 'newpriorityinput');

//add options to select
const selectHigh = document.createElement('option');
selectHigh.textContent = "High";
selectHigh.setAttribute('value', 'High')
newPriorityInput.appendChild(selectHigh);
const selectMedium = document.createElement('option');
selectMedium.textContent = "Medium";
newPriorityInput.appendChild(selectMedium);
const selectLow = document.createElement('option');
selectLow.textContent = "Low";
newPriorityInput.appendChild(selectLow);
newPriority.appendChild(newPriorityInput);

//button to submit new task to the project
const submitNewTaskBtn = document.createElement('button');
submitNewTaskBtn.textContent = "Add Task";




addTaskModal.appendChild(newTask);
addTaskModal.appendChild(newPriority);
addTaskModal.appendChild(submitNewTaskBtn);


export { addTaskModal };
export { submitNewTaskBtn };


Here's the main index.js where I have the renderSidebar() function to populate the sidebar with the projects list:
import './styles.css';
import { myProjects } from './myProjects.js';
import renderMain from './renderMain.js';
import createTask from './addTask.js';
import { addTaskModal } from './addTaskModal.js';





const mainContent = document.querySelector('#main');
const sideBar = document.querySelector('#sidebarproject');






function renderSidebar() {
    let sidebarHTML = '';
    myProjects.forEach((project, index) => {
        sidebarHTML += `<div class="projects" id="project-${index}">${project.name}</div>`

    })
    sideBar.innerHTML += sidebarHTML;
    const projects = document.querySelectorAll('.projects');
    projects.forEach(project => 
        project.addEventListener('click', renderMain)
    )
}




renderSidebar();






mainContent.appendChild(addTaskModal);



Post code as a [mcve] and include the HTML.

I notice
renderMain(event)

and
let index = parseInt(event.target.id.split('-')[1]);

This is not going to work if the event you are sending to the rendermain does not have an ID, like your delete button.
I suggest you move
localStorage.setItem('projects', JSON.stringify(myProjects)); 

to the rendermain and change
function renderMain(event) {
  let index = parseInt(event.target.id.split('-')[1]);

to
function renderMain(index,projectName)

I ALSO suggest you delegate the click to the container, then you can do
deleteBtn.classList.add('delete');   
deleteBtn.textContent = 'Delete Task';
deleteBtn.dataset.index = i;
deleteBtn.dataset.projectname = projectName;

and change
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  myProjects[index].tasks.splice(i, 1);
  localStorage.setItem('projects', JSON.stringify(myProjects)); 
  renderMain(event)
}) 

to
mainContent.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
  const tgt = e.target.closest('button.delete'); 
  if (!tgt) return; 
  myProjects[tgt.dataset.index].tasks.splice(tgt.dataset.index, 1);
  renderMain(tgt.dataset.index,tgt.dataset.projectname);
});

outside the function
Here is a simpler version of your render
const renderSidebar => () {
  sideBar.innerHTML = myProjects
  .map((project, index) => `<div class="projects" data-name="${project.name}" data-index="${index}">${project.name}</div>`).join('');
};
sideBar.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('div.projects');
  if (!tgt) return; // we did not click in a project
  renderMain(tgt.dataset.index, tgt.dataset.name)
})

In your modal, you need to capture the index
Here is the changes to addModal
submitNewTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myProjects.tasks.push(newTask);
  renderMain(myProjects.length-1,newTaskInput.value);
})


hi mplungjan, thank you so much for your answer! i'm sorry if i didn't provide enough of my code, I was worried it might be extensive, I'll edit the post to include the part you're missing. I'll try to implement with what you've already provided.Again,  thank you!

Hi mplungjan, I've included more of my code, and I noticed your input about renderMain(event), I learned in a previous project to capture the index of what I clicked this way, So in my renderSidebar() function, I've set the id of all the listed projects on the sidebar with using their indexes.. I'm not sure how to capture the index without including event click in renderMain

As for your input on capturing the index in my modal, I'm still not sure how to capture the index of the active project, as I got the index previously by clicking on the sidebar project lists..

See my update. It may not work immediately, since again I cannot test it on a working version, but you get the idea.

hi, I've tried working your solution into my code. Thank you again for taking the time to look into this.

hi mplungjan, I've spent some time reading your answer, and there are some things I havent learnt yet, like how you used .closest in renderSidebar function. I'll read into these things for now before I start working on the project again. Thank you so much for the help
